# Styling for error and success messages, and email is being sent to mailbox but without information

Tags: php, html, css

Very new to programming/webdev, trying to create a working contact form and am using one done by John Morris which he shows in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOAQ986HmzA.

When testing out the errors/success messages they are not being shown with styling.

My other problem is that I get an email from Bluehost saying the following: "There are no parts that can be shown inline."

Could this be a security or server side issue?

Once again I am very new to this stuff, so I don't exactly know what to look for.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Have rewatched and checked the code against that in the lesson. I have left the php in the index file. not sure if I should create a different file for the mailer.

index.php

```
<section class="section-contact" id="contact">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>We're happy to hear from you</h2>                
            </div>
            <?php if  ( ! empty( $errors ) ) : ?>
            <div>
                <p class="errors"><?php echo implode( '</p><p class="errors">', $errors); ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php elseif ( $sent ) : ?>
            <div class="form-messages success">
                <p>Your message was sent. We'll be in touch.</p>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="row">
                <form method="post" action="index.php" class="contact-form">
                    <div class="row">                        
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" value="<?php echo isset( $fields['name'] ) ? _e( $fields['name'] ) : '' ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" value="<?php echo isset( $fields['email'] ) ? _e( $fields['email'] ) : '' ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <label>Message</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your question" <?php echo isset( $fields['message'] ) ? _e( $fields['message'] ) : '' ?>></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <label for="human">*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                            <input type="text" name="human" placeholder="Your answer">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send it!">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
```

css

```
/* ----------------------------------------------- */
/* FORM */
/* ----------------------------------------------- */

.contact-form {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
select,
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

textarea {
    height: 100px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 0;
}

*:focus {outline: none;}

.form-messages {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}

.success { background-color: #32ad3b; }

.errors { 
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #eb5151
}
```

mailer section

```
<?php
//Helper functions. Likely place in external file
function _e( $string ) {
    return htmlentities( $string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false );
}

/* ------------------------------------------------
    STUFF YOU NEED TO CHANGE FOR YOUR SPECIFIC FORM
--------------------------------------------------*/

// Specify the foprm field names your form will accept
$whitelist = array( 'name', 'email', 'message' );

// Set the email address submssions will be sent to
$email_address = 'carlos@carlosygoadesigns.com';

// Set the subject line for the email messages
$subject = 'New Contact Form Submission';

/* ----------------------------------------------------
    END STUFF YOU NEED TO CHANGE FOR YOUR SPECIFIC FORM
------------------------------------------------------*/


// Instantiate variables we'll use
$errors = array();
$fields = array();

// Check for form submission
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

    // Validate maths
    if ( intval( $_POST['human'] ) !== 4 ) {
        $errors[] = 'Please check your maths.';
    }

    // Validate email address
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) && ! filter_var( $_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
        $errors[] = 'That is not a vaild email address';
    }

    // Perform filed whitelisting
    foreach ( $whitelist as $key ) {
        $fileds[$key] = $_POSt[$key];
    }

    // Validate field data
    foreach ( $fields as $field => $data ) {
        if ( empty( $data ) ) {
            $errors[] = 'Please enter your ' . $field;
        }
    }

    // Check and process
    if ( empty( $errors ) ) {
        $sent = mail( $email_address, $subject, $fields['message'] );
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks for any help, once again very new to this so I am really not sure what I am looking for.

Comment: As far as I can tell nothing ever gets set in the `$fields` array. Perhaps a typo: `$fileds[$key]`? And that's not the only typo I spot. Programming requires 100% accuracy.

Comment: Thank you I see it, yeah I know I have a long way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code contains two errors:

```
// Perform filed whitelisting
foreach ( $whitelist as $key ) {
    $fileds[$key] = $_POSt[$key];
}
```

Replace it with:

```
// Perform filed whitelisting
foreach ($whitelist as $key) {
    $fields[$key] = $_POST[$key];
}
```

That will fill the `$fields` array.

Comment: Thanks for that, when testing the form I now am getting the error messages that I have set, even though I have entered the inputs correctly. and they aren't styled either.

Comment: @CarlosYgoa Well, if you get any of your errors no email will be sent. That's how you programmed it. It's up to you to find out why you get these errors, since I don't know which error messages you see. I'm quite sure you don't see all of them.